# How will changing taxonomy term affect tagged nodes

Tags: drupal-7, taxonomy

What happens when a taxonomy term is changed? Will the term just change for all nodes tagged with the original term or will the relationship be deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The taxonomy term relationship is stored in the database using the term ID. So if you change that term's name, but not the ID, it should be fine. If you delete that term, the relationship will no longer exist so avoid doing that.